# Unwanted delay on Matlab command prompt

Tags: matlab

I have the situation where arbitrary Matlab commands take a long time to start executing.
This happens (seemingly) at random, but frequent enough (around every 5th time) to slow down my work.

Note that this does **not depend** on the command itself, even something simple as `tic, 1, toc` may take more than 15 seconds (sic!) and will then display

```
1
Elapsed time is 0.000608 seconds.
```

as expected. During this lag, the status bar shows "busy" and the GUI is reactive.
All of the output follows smoothly afterwards and without further delay. Hence, I assume that Matlab iself spends this time for some pre-processing.

This happens on two machines of mine and in 2013a as well as 2013b, both on Windows 7, so I expect that it has to do with my specific setup somehow.
I could imagine that one of the following is causing this, but it is particularly difficult to google this problem since most questions along the "slow matlab" keywords address the actual performance of a specific piece of code which is not the case here.

- My Matlab path may contain something it shouldn't
- The MEX-compiler interferes or is wrongly configured
- A model open in Simulink interferes (although happens also without open model)
- HDL-Coder interferes
- The fixed-point (or other) library interferes
- Wrong settings (e.g. accelleration)
- I'm often on a drive mounted by TrueCrypt (although it also happens on `C:`)

Has anyone experienced this before or any idea how to further localize the cause of those delays?

Comment: One thing I would try is to start matlab without a gui (i.e. just the command line version) and see if the problem persists. As this question is not directly code related it is probably better suited for superuser.

Comment: To test your first idea you can run `restoredefaultpath; matlabrc` to reset the path to only have MATLAB directories.

Comment: What license schema do you use? Floating license? Local license? If it's the former, Matlab may be having a hard time contacting the license server.

Comment: Also in the same vein as @Jonas is MATLAB installed on a network drive or installed locally?  The former could conceivably contribute to slowness.

Comment: Thanks for all those inputs, I'll try them now. The license is floating and installation is local. @Jonas: Any idea on how to check if its the license server connection?

Comment: @mbschenkel: you can try pinging the license server (there is a network.lic file in your installation folder with the server address). Maybe it can help to replace the server name with the IP address of the server in case the bottleneck is the DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was a licensing issue. `LM_LICENSE_FILE` contained a multitude of servers for other tools besides Matlab and one of them was not responding. Cleaning up `LM_LICENSE_FILE` as well as starting Matlab with the [`-c` command line option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html?refresh=true) solved the problem for me.